# Error response from daemon when creating hadoop container (Docker)

Tags: docker

Can any one tell me what the following driver error is telling me ....

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run -d -p 50070:50070 -p 50075:50075 -p 19888:19888 -p 8042:8042 -p 8088:8088 -p 10000:10000 psu-hadoop
1e92fe320d55f76a1405cbe690a00efac96905e92adf95cc3fa0ee3ea6d87980
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint elegant_kirch (29f8c9ff9111445550f932cab0c4adfbaaac8256a3e7a5a32c2d821dedb93570): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:50075: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

or point me in the right direction to correct.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-459205576 would help?

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V is locking the ports ....

Solution

dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcpstartport=50075 numberofports=1

dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All